# Testing AdMob integration

Tags: android, testing, admob, banner

I have a quick question about integrating AdMob into your app (in my case with Unity).

The tutorial said to use the following lines during testing:

```
return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("deviceID")
            .Build();
```

Is this supposed to show dummy ads (like UnityAds does), or real ads but give no reveue? When testing on my phone I am getting real ads I can click on and direct me to a valid app on the store. However, on the AdMob dashboard I don't get any revenue or impressions.

I just want to make sure this is correct, and I won't get into any legal trouble by faking impressions. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is demo ads, clicks will not be picked up as it is not "real" ads. I'm not sure if it is legal to click on them but why would you want to...

Comment: Those are demo ads and there is no legality issue with them as admob opens them deliberately. You will be served by ad-server but ad-tracker at the admob servers silently by passes the events/impression recorded. It checks for associated token values and userid which should be in desired format for considering it as a event.

Comment: Great! One more thing, when I release my app to play store is it against the TOS to test that the ads are working from my own account? I ask because I am using AdMob Mediation and AdMob ads work perfectly, but ads from UnityAds seem to not be working properly and I am wondering if it is just because I am in development mode (I have already asked at the AdMob Mediation github but have heard nothing back yet). Thanks!